# Reordering a repeating field in Biztalk

Tags: mapping, biztalk, repeat

I have an identical source and destination schema in Biztalk, but one of the fields is a repeating field. How do I re-order this field in a specific way when doing mapping?

For example, the source and destination schema look like this:

```
Order (this is repeating)
-ID
-Name
```

So an example input would look like this:

```
<Order>
<ID>123</ID>
<NAME>ORDERID</NAME>
</Order>
<Order>
<ID>7682</ID>
<NAME>CUSTOMERID</NAME>
</Order>
<Order>
<ID>5555</ID>
<NAME>ITEMID</NAME>
</Order>
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
<Order>
<ID>7682</ID>
<NAME>CUSTOMERID</NAME>
</Order>
<Order>
<ID>123</ID>
<NAME>ORDERID</NAME>
</Order>
<Order>
<ID>5555</ID>
<NAME>ITEMID</NAME>
</Order>
```

The ordering is such that the first and second values swap with each other. Is this doable in the map or must this be done as a pipeline component? I am trying to avoid orchestration.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting can be done by use xsl:sort in a custom xsl. 
   You may have to write some xslt code to complete this task.